# Retrying alternative endpoints on python scraping request

Tags: python, lxml

I'm running the below code which seems to work ok. However, the URL I am requesting is https://api.gov.au/definitions/api/definition/**fs/** and and I know this will fail sometimes because for a given concept the correct url may end in https://api.gov.au/definitions/api/definition/**trc/**

What I want to do is try the /fs url and if that doesn't work then try the /trc url and if that doesn't work then just print an empty record with the input value from concepts as the first column.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

conceptCSV = pd.read_csv("Concepts.csv")
conceptCSV.columns = ["type", "id", "name"]
concepts = list(conceptCSV.id)
concept_list = []


for concept in concepts:
    JSONContent = requests.get("https://api.gov.au/definitions/api/definition/fs/" + concept.lower()).json()['content']
    if 'error' not in JSONContent:
        concept_list.append([
            JSONContent['name'],
            JSONContent['domain'],
            JSONContent['status'],
            JSONContent['definition'],
            JSONContent['guidance'],
            JSONContent['identifier'],
            JSONContent['type'],
            JSONContent['domainAcronym'],
            JSONContent['sourceURL']
        ])


dataset = pd.DataFrame(concept_list)
dataset.columns = ['name', 'domain', 'status', 'definition',
                   'guidance', 'identifier', 'type', 'domainAcronym', 'sourceURL']


dataset.to_csv("conceptDetails.csv", index=False)
```

Many thanks
Michael

Answer (score 1):

If you know either of the url is going to work, you can try the following. Offcource you can plug-in some decorator but in your case it seems an overkill.

```
for concept in concepts:
    r = requests.get("https://api.gov.au/definitions/api/definition/fs/" + concept.lower())
    if r.status_code == 200:
        JSONContent = r.json()['content']
    else:
        r = requests.get("https://api.gov.au/definitions/api/definition/trc/" + concept.lower())
        if r.status_code == 200:
            JSONContent = r.json()['content']

    if JSONContent:
        if 'error' not in JSONContent:
            concept_list.append([
                JSONContent['name'],
                JSONContent['domain'],
                JSONContent['status'],
                JSONContent['definition'],
                JSONContent['guidance'],
                JSONContent['identifier'],
                JSONContent['type'],
                JSONContent['domainAcronym'],
                JSONContent['sourceURL']
            ])
```